# Set conditional on template based on a refering page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-referer

I am trying to create a conditional template in wordpres where the condition should only be passed if the referring page is the search page:

I am aware that url_to_postid(wp_get_referer()) would get me the page id of the refering page but in my case this does not work as the search page does not have an id. Is there any other way I can do this?

EDIT: the wordpress url for the search would be http:/mywebsite.com/?s=aaa where is the search term

Comment: Best will be to pass a value via the URL

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your using this for and how reliable it needs to be you  could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Taken from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

*The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.*

You might be better off either using post/get to send a parameter to the next page, or using a session if you need more reliability and or control.

Comment: `wp_get_referrer()` is just a wrapper for `HTTP_REFERER`, they do exactly the same job. As you noted, it is totally unreliable, really a mickey mouse function ;-)

Comment: agree, need some more information on structure/process to be able to offer any reliable info. On a side note, why would wordpress create a wrapper for the fn, why not just use `HTTP_REFERER`, seems crazy to me

Comment: @atoms have added how the url would be structured